# How can I improve the iCloud to request the image? Can iCloud be used with SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

```
CKContainer *c=  [CKContainer defaultContainer];
CKDatabase *openbase=c.publicCloudDatabase;

CKDatabase *privateDatabase=c.privateCloudDatabase;

NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
CKQuery *q=[[CKQuery alloc]initWithRecordType:@"Notesss" predicate:predicate];

[openbase performQuery:q inZoneWithID:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray<CKRecord *> * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    } else {
        [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CKRecord * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        NSString *title= [obj valueForKey:@"title"];
        if( [title containsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)row+1]]){
            CKAsset *imageA=[obj valueForKey:@"dataImage"];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.imageV.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageA.fileURL.path];
            });
        };
    }];
}}];
```

1. Is it current to request from iCloud?
2. Can I use SDWebImage when I request from iCloud?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? CloudKit is based on iCloud, but it's not the same. What do you want to improve. I don't understand your questions completely.

In your code I see you already get the image from the CloudKit record / CKAsset. What else do you want to do with it?. The moment you have the CKAsset the image is just a file on your phone. You can do whatever you want with it.